# Multiple tabs don't buffer videos in the background on Safari

Tags: safari, macos, video, tabs

some have touched this issue but not in a way to solve my problem.
Im running Safari 10.0.3 on Sierra 10.12.3 and i usually load multiple sites and try to buffer videos while working on something else, instead of waiting for them to load in order to watch them because my connection isn't that fast.
My issue is that the videos won't buffer unless their tabs are active.
This is counter-productive for me. I don't want to open that video tab and just stare at the bar to load, which might take 15 or more minutes.
Is there a setting/plug-in that would help in that regard?
Thanks

Comment: Are you mainly looking for a solution that works with a particular site(s)  (e.g. YouTube, Vimeo) or do you need it to work with any site?

Comment: Thx for answering. Yes a general solution